# Prob step in kendo details

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/styles/kendo.default-v2.min.css"/>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="numerictextbox" />
<script>
  $("#numerictextbox").kendoNumericTextBox();
  var numerictextbox = $("#numerictextbox").data("kendoNumericTextBox");
  var step = numerictextbox.step();
  numerictextbox.step(0.01);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

i want to change the step of the input to 0.001 but its not work.
if someone have any idea 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put 0.001 instead of 0.01. You also need to change the number of decimals to 3, because default is 2.

```js
$("#numerictextbox").kendoNumericTextBox({ decimals: 3 });
var numerictextbox = $("#numerictextbox").data("kendoNumericTextBox");
var step = numerictextbox.step();
numerictextbox.step(0.001);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/styles/kendo.default-v2.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<input id="numerictextbox" />
```